# How to show list of available choices on a sharepoint form

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-form, modern-experience

I have a simple sharepoint form added called 'laptop borrowing request' which has employee name, date and laptop as fields. Laptop is a choice column: surface, thinkad and laptop. There are only three devices physically present at client.

Now the following seems difficult to implement for me: 
1. Let's say if couple of users have put in request and they have acquired possession of thinkpad and laptop ,so only surface is available to request.

If the next person puts in a request for thinkpad, how do I show that its not available or restrict to put in a request for thinkpad.

Please share thoughts if any, thanks. I am working SP online modern.

Answer (score 2):

This is where PowerApps could help. PowerApps supports filters to generate drop-down lists. The powerapps side would be easiest if you could update the list of items to indicate which items are available. (so, a separate "status" field that is updated when a user checks something out or returns an item, which could be done via a workflow (Flow)).

Comment: Excellent idea, never thought about it. For now I just added a simple list with yes/no filed and added it to a web part and seems to work